# Facebook Page access token - Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, token

I have an App and a page and I autopost on this page using the app. It was working fine but it has stopped posting.
I get this error:

`{"error":{"message":"Error validating access token: The session has been invalidated because the user has changed the password.","type":"OAuthException","code":190,"error_subcode":460,}}`

I have changed my password soon but I didn't know that would affect app. Now, I generated again never expiring access token and I set it in my code but it's showing this error again.

In facebook app debugger it's showing my App Id, profile ID, user ID and the following data:

```html
Expires Never
Valid True
Origin Web
Scopes read_insights, manage_pages, publish_pages, pages_manage_cta, publish_actions, public_profile
```

How should I fix that?